# Why do germanium transistors and silicon transistors have different conditions for cutoff region in common emitter configuration?

Tags: transistors, pnp, common-emitter

The textbook I currently read defines cut-off for ***PNP*** germanium transistors like this:

> For germanium transistors, however,
>   cutoff for switching purposes will be defined as those conditions that exist when \$ I_C = I_{CBO} \$

and they continue saying that:

> This condition can normally be obtained for germanium transistors by reverse-biasing the base-to-emitter junction a few tenths of a volt.

whereas for silicon transistors it is said that:

> Since \$ I_{CEO} \$ is typically low in magnitude for silicon materials, cutoff will exist for switching purposes when
>   \$ I_B = 0 mA \$ or \$ I_C = I_{CEO} \$ for silicon transistors only.

where $$ I_{CEO} = I_{CBO} / (1 - \alpha) | when I_B = 0 $$

and where \$ \alpha = I_C / I_E\$

So, **my question** is why is the condition for cut-off \$I_{CEO}\$ for *silicon* transistors and \$I_{CBO}\$ for *germanium* ones, even though both of them are operated in the same configuration (Common Emitter).

And also why are they talking about reverse biasing germanium transistors when cut-off already means base-to-emitter junction is reverse biased?

My initial thoughts are that for germanium \$I_{CEO}\$ is high, so that's why \$I_{CBO}\$ is needed.

Comment: do these two materials have different avalance behaviors?

Comment: probably yes. But what does it have to do with cut-off region ?